# difficulty using rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I make an html table in this structure?

```
+--------------+-----+--------------+
|              |     |              |
|  CONTENT-1   |     |  CONTENT-2   |
|--------------|     |--------------|
|              |     |              |
|              |     |              |
|              |     |              |
|              |     |              |
|              |     |              |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I've tried with a rowspan on the tall column, but it's not working correctly.

```
<table class="login_selection_button">
    <tr>
        <td>
            CONTENT-1
        </td>
        <td>
            CONTENT-2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KyttF/

THANKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the cell with the rowspan in the first row and give it a width

http://jsfiddle.net/KyttF/1/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            CONTENT-1
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="width:50px;"></td>
        <td>
            CONTENT-2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            filler
        </td>
        <td>
            filler
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Giving the cell a width is quite independent of the problem and the solution.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela why don't you give your own answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        content 1
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
    </td>
    <td>
        content 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```